# StreamBuilder in map and slow UI in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have an app with GoogleMaps with this code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(CustomCollectionPath.beets)
        .where('email', isNotEqualTo: currentUser.email)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((docSnapshot) async {
          if (docSnapshot.data() is Map<String, dynamic>) {
            Map<String, dynamic> beetData =
                docSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

            GeoPoint geoPoint = beetData['coordinates'];

            LatLng coordinates = LatLng(
              geoPoint.latitude,
              geoPoint.longitude,
            );

            String email = beetData['email'];

            UserModel? user = await fetchUserData(email);

            BitmapDescriptor markerUser =
                await MarkerIcon.downloadResizePictureCircle(
                    user!.urlImage,
                    size: 190,
                    addBorder: true,
                    borderColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
                    borderSize: 24);

            setState(() {
              markers.add(Marker(
                markerId: MarkerId(docSnapshot.id),
                onTap: () async {
                  await openInfoModalUser(context, user);
                },
                position: coordinates,
                icon: markerUser,
              ));
            });
          }
        });
        return GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            buildingsEnabled: true,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            zoomControlsEnabled: false,
            markers: markers.toSet(),
            mapToolbarEnabled: false,
            initialCameraPosition: _startPosition);
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Errore durante il recupero dei dati');
      } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    },
  ),
```

my fetchUserData function:

```
Future<UserModel?> fetchUserData(String email) async {
  try {
    DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(CustomCollectionPath.userInfo)
        .doc(email)
        .get();

    if (userSnapshot.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userData =
          userSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

      UserModel user = UserModel(
        id: Random().nextInt(999999),
        name: userData['name'],
        urlImage: userData['imageUrl'],
        roleDescription: 'Role',
        description: userData['description'],
        icon: Icons.abc,
        color: Colors.red,
      );

      return user;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Errore durante il recupero dei dati utente: $e');
    return null;
  }
}
```

with **setState** my app is very slow.
however, if I remove it, it's not notified of the change, and if a pin changes, it's not changed on the map.

obviously without the setState the app is very fluid

what would be the best thing to do?

Comment: Have you run your code in release mode (`flutter run --release`) and verified that the issue persists? There are multiple optimizations for release that aren't available during development.

Comment: @offworldwelcome app crash

Comment: Did you consider moving the call to `setState` outside of the `snapshot.data!.docs.forEach(` loop, so that is only calls once - instead of for each document?

Comment: Do not build the stream in the stream: parameter of the streambuilder.  Lift it out into state.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This MapsScreen widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.